# error: cannot convert 'GtkCheckButton*' {aka '_GtkCheckButton*'} to 'GtkWidget*' {aka '_GtkWidget*'} in initialization

Tags: gtk, gtk3

So i have several check buttons I want to initialize and for some reason they are not working when i call them I get the error as shown in the title.

```
   GtkComboBox* searchSetting = GTK_COMBO_BOX(application -> get_object("searchTypeSelecter"));
   GtkWidget *checkAll = GTK_CHECK_BUTTON(application-> get_object("checkAll"));
   GtkWidget *checkFood = GTK_CHECK_BUTTON(application-> get_object("checkFood"));
   GtkWidget *checkFuel = GTK_CHECK_BUTTON(application-> get_object("checkFuel"));
   GtkWidget *checkParking = GTK_CHECK_BUTTON(application-> get_object("checkParking"));
```

My partner made several objects from other things(not check buttons) like he did with searchSetting, and that worked perfectly fine. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please provide a minimal and reproducible example. From the provided code, it is not possible to know the source of the error.

Comment: What is `application`? Is it a `GtkBuilder`? Is this part in C++?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're seeing this is because you're doing what the error message mentions: you're casting the result of `application->get_object()`, whatever return type that may have, as `GtkCheckButton*`. In other words, you're doing something like this:

```
GtkWidget *a = (GtkCheckButton*) b; // Doesn't even matter how b was declared earlier
```

GTK's widgets are written in C, so they don't have a concept of polymorphism. To the compiler, they're just pointers, and the "OOP" that GTK (and its underlying framework GObject) uses, requires you to also "upcast" variables where needed. In other words, you have 2 options:

Cast to `GtkCheckButton*` and upcast to GtkWidget when using GtkWidget API.

```c
    GtkCheckButton *checkAll = GTK_CHECK_BUTTON(application-> get_object("checkAll"));
    // later...
    gtk_widget_show(GTK_WIDGET(checkAll));
```

Cast to `GtkWidget*`:

```c
    GtkWidget *checkAll = GTK_WIDGET(application-> get_object("checkAll"));
    // later...
    gtk_widget_show(checkAll);
```